# OpenGL es can't draw polygons

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, objective-c++

I've been trying to port my engine to iOS, but I've had a few setbacks with getting it to render anything. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1) to get started, but to no success. When I started a separate project to follow the tutorial exactly and got up to the "draw a sprite" part, but I still can't get polygons to draw.

This is the code for my renderer:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ESSprite.h"

struct vertex
{
    float x, y, z;

};

struct vertex vertices[4];

GLuint* ind;


GLuint vbuffer, ibuffer;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext* context;
@property (strong) GLKBaseEffect* effect;
@property (strong) ESSprite* player;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize context = _context;
@synthesize player = _player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context)
    {
        NSLog(@"Didn't work...");
    }

    GLKView* view = (GLKView*)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, screen.size.width, 0, screen.size.height, 1, 1024);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    glViewport(0, 0, screen.size.width, screen.size.height);

    //start draw setup
    vertices[0].x = 0.0f;
    vertices[0].y = 0.0f;

    vertices[1].x = 100.0f;
    vertices[1].y = 0.0f;

    vertices[2].x = 100.0f;
    vertices[2].y = 100.0f;

    vertices[3].x = 0.0f;
    vertices[3].y = 100.0f;


    ind = malloc(sizeof(GLuint) *4); //sprites only need 4 vertices

    // this will be more complex in the mesh class
    ind[0] = 0;
    ind[1] = 1;
    ind[2] = 3;
    ind[3] = 2;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(struct vertex), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLuint), ind, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


    //self.player = [[ESSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"sinncaSprite.png" effect:self.effect];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - GLKViewDelegate

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.24f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);

    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 4 * sizeof(struct vertex), vertices);
    //glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct vertex), (GLvoid*)struct vertex);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct vertex), 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //[self.player render];
}

- (void)update
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibuffer);
    free(ind);
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Why am I having so much difficulty drawing a simple polygon?

Comment: Do you see the clear colour? In vertex pointer set 2 dimensions instead of 3 OR set the Z coordinates of your vertex buffer to .0f. How is this supposed to be drawn? Do you have any texture or at least some polygon colour?

Comment: Actually since you set zNear to 1.0f and zFar to 1024f in your GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho you will not be able to see any point that has Z coordinate out of those bounds. Try some negative value for zNear and also try setting some constant colour on your effect.

Comment: I changed the zNear to -1024, set the z coordinates to 0.0f, and set the constant color to white, but I'm still getting this blank screen. However, I am seeing the clear color.